# Objective C - Global variables for every View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm learning Objective C & Xcode, by doing my first App.
First a user has to sign in. And then he can do several things, like joining a group or changing his data (username, email,...).

The Login is finished and it works fine. 
To the question:

Is it possible to set a variable which I can reach from every View Controller?

I tried it with the segues, but I think it's very hard to define this in every View Controller.

I'm searching for a global variable which I can reach from everywhere in the App, is this possible?
Or is there an other method to solve this?

Thank you for the help!
Emanuel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would personally advise you to use the Singleton pattern.
I would not recommend putting everything into AppDelegate, this class is not meant for that.

Instead, what you can do is create a dedicated class (with a name like "ApplicationState", or whatever suits you), and put the properties you need in its header file, and having your singleton management code in the .m (and the prototype in the header)

If you need the singleton management code, here it is:

```
+ (ApplicationState*)sharedInstance
{
    static ApplicationState* sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Then, if you have in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject* object;

+ (ApplicationState*)sharedInstance;
```

You will be able to get this variable from anywhere by including the ApplicationState header file, and call:

```
[[ApplicationState sharedInstance] object];
```

Comment: what subclass should i choose for the "ApplicationState"-Class? thanks

Comment: NSObject is just fine.

Comment: Thank you! And how do I set the variable? [[ApplicationState sharedInstance] userMail];

Comment: You can do:

    [[ApplicationState sharedInstance] setUserMail:@"YOUR USER MAIL"];

Comment: applicationState expected a type ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSUserdefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if its simple .

**Save:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:username forKey:@"userName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];    
 NSLog(@"username saved = %@", username);
```

**Read:**

```
NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
NSLog(@"username retrieved = %@", username);
```

Comment: Where do I have to declare the String (in your example "username")?

Comment: its up to you, it could be a local variable, or a property like in @kuliay example `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;`

Comment: i have to access it in every other classes, so a local wouldn't be good.... and when i declare it in appdelegate, do i have to make a new object in every new class of appdelegate (so the variable is empty, or not??)? thanks for the help!

Comment: so make it a property

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppDelegate as well.

Define a property in your AppDelegate.h,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;
```

And then in your view controller, after importing AppDelegate.h,

```
AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@", appDel.userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in plist or you can create Objective-C class initialize your variables within and import header in .pch file, then this class with data will available in every ViewController